# Turning 1 column into 2

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem where I am only give a container div with around 10 divs inside. I would like to find a way to turn this 1 column of divs into 2 columns without adding additional divs (ie. not adding divs for left column or right columns). I can and most preferably would like to find a CSS solution.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Ideal output:

```
1      2
3      4
5      6
```

I tried fooling around with floating but it didn't work out too well. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What was the problem with floating? That is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: What browsers are you trying to target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Qzj2d/ ? That is the simplest solution (not necessary the prettiest one).

Comment: Exactly what I did :D Upboats for you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Set your inner divs to half the width of your container and float them. e.g.

```
.container { width:600px;}

.container div {
   width:300px;
   float:left;
}
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/k2tQG/

Answer (score 0):

I think `display: inline-block` is better than `float`, because heights of elements might vary. But you'll need to set `font-size` to `0` on `.container` and then reset it on elements.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x95QY/)

Answer (score 0):

i know that the more suitable solution has already been posted here and support is heavily lacking for the proposal that I am going to make but you can separate any div into any number of columns using the new ccs3 column-count and column-gap properties.

A link to this can be seen here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

I am quite disappointed that support for this is so low because these properties will allow for true 'print-style' layouts and if supported we would not have to clear:both to make our parent div and child divs align correctly. i know that i am opening up a can of worms here but this is by far the best option to use.

I hear so many people asking about column layouts so why oh why can we not have support to use technology that is already out there...?? Sorry for the rant